# PyCairo drawing mask on an image

Tags: python, cairo, pycairo

I'm trying to write a program that displays the masks found by a watershed algorithm in an interactive DrawingArea using PyCairo in PyGObject, however I cannot get it to display.

```
    def draw_region(self, mask):
        cr = cairo.Context(self.image_surface)
        surface = cairo.ImageSurface.create_for_data(mask, cairo.FORMAT_A1, mask.shape[1], mask.shape[0])
        cr.set_source_rgb(1, 0, 0)
        cr.mask_surface(surface)
        cr.fill()
```

This function should take a binary mask and display it as red on the DrawingArea. I believe the rest of my code is setup correctly and this function to be the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: No idea about the question, but for debugging, you could try `surface.write_to_png("/tmp/image.png")`.

Comment: Also: That `cr.fill()` call is redundant. `mask_surface()` is already a drawing verb.